# Firebase A/B test user variant information not available in Google Analytics clickstream tables

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, firebase-ab-testing

I'm looking to report on the outcome of a Firebase A/B test using Google Analytics / BigQuery tables.

To do this I need to identify the test group each user was in.

The Firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing/ab-concepts) suggests *experiment and variant memberships are stored as user properties on every GA event in the normal GA event tables.*

However, I can't find this information associated with GA events in the GA interface or BQ clickstream tables - I can only see it in the Firebase tables.

Where should I be looking? I've checked the Event Action, Event Category, Event Label etc. dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Use in your query to identify it
userProperty.value.string_value where userProperty.key = 'firebase_exp_000'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).